# Hardone PSD to HTML task

Tags: html, psd

I have some difficulties with doing PSD to HTML conversion. Please look at section #2 - in that section, the task is the following: two blocks must be equal height, must be liquid and NO javascript (any - jquery etc..) usage! I've done research in that PSD to HTML conversion - [This is my version](http://www.nulllogic.net/_1/test3) [Here is the full PSD image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pneG.jpg)

```
My variation sheme:
/---------------------------------\
|              |  |                |
| sdfdsfsdf    |S |  fsdfdsfsdf    |
| fdsfsdfds    |P |  fdfsdfsfsd    |
|              |A |  sdffsdf       |   
|              |C |                |
|              |E |  fsdfssf       |
|              |  |  sdfsfs        |
|              |  |  gdf           |
\---------------------------------/
This go messy with IE6 and small resolutions - <400px
```

Two block are with round corners - they must be equal height

I forgot to add that support of IE6 is a must :(

Comment: [Global Stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-RU-monthly-201201-201202) says that you have 1.13% IE6 Users, Microsoft has dropped any support for IE, and any legal installation of Windows now automatically asks the user to update their browser.
It is time to tell your boss/client, that there is not going to be any IE.

Answer (score 1):

For attaining equal heights of block like in your case you can make use of tables which are simple enough to use. But I always recommend div layouts, for div layouts you can make use of the display properties. e.g

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
   content
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    content
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper{ width:1024px; display:table;}
.left,.right{display:table-cell; width:500px;margin:0 6px}
```

but this display:table-cell won't work on IE 6.

in that case you can make use of the padding and negative margin e.g

```
.left,.right{float:left; width:500px; padding-bottom:2000px; margin-bottom:-2000px; }
```

Comment: I forgot to add that support of IE6 is a must :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use table display css to make 2 block be equal height:

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.column.one {
  background-color: #00c8d2;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.column.two {
  background-color: #bababa;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column one">
  </div>
  <div class="column two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use simple `<table><tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td></table>` structure which will support in all browsers.